# How to get textarea value from many different textarea with the same IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get a value from  many different `textarea` tags with same IDs using jQuery? I also need to allow the user a choice of which `textarea` he/she wants to add a comment, and then get the comment.

### This is my HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wall_post">
        <p>First Post</p>
        <textarea id="user_comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your comment here"></textarea>
    </div>
        <div class="wall_post">
            <p>Second Post</p>
        <textarea id="user_comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your comment here"></textarea>
    </div>
        <div class="wall_post">
            <p>Third Post</p>
        <textarea id="user_comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your comment here"></textarea>
    </div>
        <div class="wall_post">
            <p>Fourth Post</p>
        <textarea id="user_comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your comment here" ></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery so far

This jQuery only prints out the first `textarea` value, but is ignoring the others.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var targetInput = $('#user_comment');

    if(!targetInput.is(document.activeElement)) {
        alert('Typed while not focused on #myInput!');
    }else{
        if(e.which == 13){
        alert(targetInput.val());
         targetInput.val('');

        }
  }
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: IDs should be always unique..

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context... So use class instead

Comment: Id's should be unique instead of id's try using class.

Comment: ok but this project is like facebook feeds, the feeds are generated from database and I try to append in the textarea with same id but how can i get a value from that specified textarea. Remember the textareas are very many. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ids must be unique. You can rather use classname.

Also you can use target to get current keydown element:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
 var targetInput = $(e.target);
   if(!targetInput.is('textarea')) {
      alert('Typed while not focused on #myInput!');
   }else{
     if(e.which == 13){
       alert(targetInput.val());
       targetInput.val('');
    }
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jwjzdse3/)**

Comment: please remove it. i just added it for debugging the code.

Comment: Note that `if(!targetInput.is($(document.activeElement)))` will never fire as the targetInput will always be the activeElement as that is what has been selected.

Comment: @RichardDalton, you know am not good at this so how can i change it

Comment: Should rather use  `if(!targetInput.is('textarea')) {`

Answer (score 0):

As ID's are expected to be unique jQuery will return the first element, not a list of all with that ID.

To access all of your textareas you could use this selector (assuming there is only a single text area with each `wall_post` div:

```
$('.wall_post textarea')
```

You could bind your keydown event to this instead as well:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.wall_post textarea', function(e) {
    // do whatever you need to with this textarea
});
```